# Bind comma-separated string to List

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a form with a text-input element.

The user can enter values separated by commas like "a,b,c,d". In my model, there's a List which should then hold these values (which really are a list).

In Thymeleaf, how can I bind such a string and convert it to a list on submit? Is there something like a Converter interface?

Comment: Are you talking about only conversion or binding the values as well?

Comment: @RossiRobinsion I want to bind the values (bidirectional conversion) if possible.

Answer (score 1):

In your Model instead of List you can use String to populate the input values. After you get the values, you can do following:

You will probably have a String something like this: "text1, text2, text3...". Then convert it to a List you can do something like this:

```
String value = "text1, text2, text3..."
List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(value.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

The regex basically removes the whitespace and the comma. This should work fine.

Comment: I know but I don't want to pollute my (domain-)model with an unecessary property. Is there a best practice to create PresentationModels with Thymeleaf? Or can I just hold such a string in the controller? I'd really like to specify a converter.